# Building a New Column of Variations of Pair Combinations Found in Two Given Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

If I have two columns of information in an Excel spreadsheet, for example:

```
Col A   Col B

Taegu,  Pusan
Pusan,  Pusan
Seoul,  Shanghai
Kōchi,  Osaka
Guangzhou,  Dalian
Tokyo,  Tokyo
Tokyo, Shanghai
Taegu,  Taegu
Changchun,  Dalian
Pusan, Pusan
Changchun, Dalian
Tokyo, Shanghai
```

I'm trying, ultimately, to count the number of each unique pair (though I don't care which order they are listed), ignoring cases where the from and two are the same. The first step, I guess, would be to create a column which lists all the unique pairs (regardless of what order the pair is listed in).

What is the best way to write a formula, for example, that, given the above, would produce, in two new columns each unique pair (non-directional):

```
Taegu, Pusan, 1
Seoul, Shanghai, 1
Kōchi, Osaka, 1
Guangzhou, Dalian, 1
Changchun, Dalian, 2
Shanghai, Tokyo, 2
```

Comment: I tried playing around with pivot tables, but this seemed to be more useful counting one column, not combination of columns. I tried concatenation of columns, but then not sure how to handle the lack of need to be directional (as then Shanghai, Tokyo gets recognized differently from Tokyo, Shanghai while they should both be counted in total)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### With Formulas

**Note:** `UNIQUE` and `FILTER` functions are available only on Excel365.

1. You can combine the `UNIQUE` and `FILTER` functions to obtain the list of pairs. You can try the following formula:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER($A$2:$B$13,$A$2:$A$13<>$B$2:$B$13))
```

2. After obtaining the list, you can use `COUNTIFS` to count the numbers of each pair.

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$13,D3,$B$2:$B$13,E3)
```

[image: IMG:]

[image: IMG:]

### Through Power Query

1. Select your data/range. On the Data tab, on the Get & Transform Data group, select From Table/Range.
2. Click on Add Column tab. Click on Custom Column. Give the column a name and enter the formula below.

```
= if [ColA] <> [ColB] then ([ColA] & " - " & [ColB]) else null
```

[image]

Click OK. You will obtain this:

[image]

3. Click on the Transform tab, then click on Group by. Select the column created on the previous step. On the New Column, enter a name. On the Operations box, select Count Rows. Click Ok.

[image]

You will obtain this:

[image]

4. Click on the arrow next to Pairs column, then deselect `null`. On the Home tab, click on Close and load. A table will be created with this result:

[image]

Comment: Nice one you are getting +1 ☺ But I've suggestion also, the method ,,, ( DYNAMIC ARRAY ) you have used , restricts with higher versions,, better U add CAVEAT with your post !

Comment: @RajeshS Should I add more assumptions on the part where I wrote "UNIQUE and FILTER functions are available only on Excel365"?

Comment: This looks fantastic and I'm very grateful for all the detail. It is Sunday here but I'll try this out and if it works I'll select as answer. For now upvoting it.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio,, The Note section should be used as CAVEAT on top,,, was my concern only,,, since OP has used TAG `microsoft-excel`, and no where mentioned that is using the higher version !!

Comment: Although for some reason, the formulas didn't work for me (I have 365), with some weird results, but I think the problem is likely with my data. The first formula will get rid of exact duplicates, but doesn't recognise that Tokyo Shanghai and Shanghai Tokyo are the same (it assumes they are two unique pairs). Thanks for your time and I have labeled this the answer.